# How to control where bootstrap breaks the text on collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.  I have an application with the title "A Taste of San Diego, California".

### A Taste of San Diego, California

When the screen is desktop size this displays nicely in one line.  It still looks great when the screen collapses to tablet size.  But when I get to smartphone size the text breaks like this;

Line 1:  A Taste of San
Line 2: Diego, California

I have searched the Internet far and wide and even asked my Bootstrap tutor about how to keep "San Diego" together as if it were one word.  I think it would even be better if it broke into 3 lines, if it has to;

Line 1: A Taste of
Line 2: San Diego,
Line 3: California

How can I control where the text breaks on collapse?  Is the only solution to put it into 3 lines to begin with?

Comment: Can you post some code?  And one way I can think of off the top of my head is setting `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: have u tried this?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18501487/4810628

Comment: @Mark the white-space nowrap will make it into a one-liner, and that is another problem

Comment: @DexterHuinda No reason you couldn't do `<span style="white-space: nowrap">San Diego</span>` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `San&nbsp;Diego` to keep "San" and "Diego" together.

`&nbsp;` is a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: The funny thing is that neither my college professor or the rest of the class could come up with this simple answer.  It works brilliantly, of course.  And such a simple fix.  It's one of the first things you learn when studying HTML and yet nobody else thought of it.  Too funny.

Comment: Maybe your college professor is not well-researched. Yes that was a simple fix, it's also a basic knowledge when studying html.

Comment: Well, in all fairness I don't think the problem was whether anyone was "well-researched".  Everyone was trying to come up with a solution in Bootstrap and basic HTML wasn't part of the thought process.  Just one of those interesting mind tricks.